# How to compare columns value to it's relationship column values laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to filter result according to value in it's relationship table
basically i have two tables i.e product_supplier and product_competitor and a product_id column in product_competitor table

```
Product::with(['ProductCompetiter'])->where('sku' , 'A898-38')->first();
```

by running above query am getting following result along with product_competitor

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "sku": "A898-38",
  "brand_id": 1,
  "supplier_id": 2,
  "name": "Sabots noirs microfibre Abeba pointure 38",
  "stock": 3,
  "price": "49.45",
  "real_price": 5,
  "last_stock_update": "2021-12-10",
  "last_price_update": "2021-12-09",
  "suggested_price": 67.23,
  "product_competiter": {
    "id": 3751,
    "product_id": 1,
    "competitor_id": 2,
    "price": 67.23
  }
}
```

relation in product model

```
public function ProductCompetiter(){
       return $this->hasOne(ProductCompetiter::class)->orderBy('price', 'asc');
   }
```

basically I want to compare **real_price** and **product_competiter.price**. if **real_price** is greater then **product_competiter.price** then only i want to show result.

Thankyou

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by `Compare` Do you want the compare in the query or to compare in PHP

Comment: In Query, I want to compare real_price and product_competiter.price. if real_price is greater then product_competiter.price then only i want to show product.

Comment: So You basically want to select all the Product which ```real_price``` is less than or equal to **minimum** ```price``` of ```product_competiters```  table right ?

Comment: yes i want product in which real_price is less than or equal to minimum price of product_competiters

Comment: It's maybe helpful : ` ->where('real_price', '<=' , 'product_competiter.price')`. add this to your query.

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 0):

If you use this comparison pretty frequently, you can make a helper method in `Product` model like:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    // More of your code here...
    public function isCheaperThanCompetitor(): bool
    {
        return $this->price < $this->productCompetiter->price;
    }
}
```

---

A bit out of topic, want to give you some tips to cast the `price` to float like:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'price' => 'float',
    ];
}
```

Comment: what if i want all result i mean if run query Product::with(['ProductCompetiter'])->get(); and also i want to compare real_price and product_competiter.price then? i want to show result only if real_price > product_competiter.price

Comment: I see, if that's the case you need to make that comparison into a scope